# How do I open a tg:// URL on Android?

Tags: telegram, url

I have a `tg://` URL like `tg://login?token=BTGjK95sf6QLckQBAZPtH_gSLOcpQoasQLCea18O9A` that I want to open in the Android Telegram app.

If I paste it into Chrome address bar then it searches for the URL, rather than redirecting to the app like on a PC.

How do I open this URL?

Comment: That the link is not executed is related to the Chrome address bar. If the link is contained in an HTML page it should work. A simple "workaround" would be to send the link in an HTML E-Mail to an account that is set-up in an E-Mail app on your device. Clicking the link in the email app on your device should open it in Telegram or whatever app the URL scheme belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around using the Telegram app and the data encoded as a QR code: open Telegram app → tap the Hamburger icon → Settings → Devices → Scan QR Code.

Comment: This edit is much less readable.